# Sorting ArrayList based based on String

Tags: java, android, sorting

i have array list of country objects (name property is in arabic) I'm retrieving from a webservice, how can i sort this list based on the name property, can you please help me
regards,

Answer (score 0):

Sort `List` alphabetically:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(listOfCountryNames);
```

or sort `ArrayList`:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

Comment: country is an object having many properties

Comment: then you have to make your own comparator based on your choice